# Checking fot transient messages with Frank/Cucumber

Tags: frank, cucumber-cpp

I am very new to Frank/Cucumber and hope you can help.  I am trying to test an iOS app and am writing a test to assure that logging in with bad credentials fails.  I am able to enter credentials and attempt to login but this results in a message that is displayed for about 4 seconds before disappearing and returning the user to the login screen.  I am trying to use the syntax

Then I wait to see "error message"

but I just enter into a 4 minute timeout before failing.  Is there something else I should be using or considering to trap and recognize this transient message?

Thanks,

Pat

Comment: Does the error message literally have the accessibilityLabel "error message"? The syntax you posted will look for a view with an accessibilityLabel which includes "error message".

Comment: Yes.  I use 'frank inspect' to trap the screen when in progress and "error message" is the accessibilityLabel for the UILabel.